# How to change speed at which text is printed (python)

Tags: python

What I am trying to accomplish is first text appears after 1 second. then 2, ect. till 10. then when time equals 10, the time decreases, so the text appears after 9 seconds, then 8 etc.

How could I fix this code so that it works properly?

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Eric/Dropbox/time.py", line 13, in <module>
    time.sleep(time)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'sleep'
```

The code :

```
import time
x = 1
t = 1
time = t + 1
while x == 1:


    print time
    if time >=10:
        time = t - 1
    elif time <= 0:
        time = t + 1
    time.sleep(time)
```

---

Edit:

```
import time
x = 1
t = 1
time1 = 0
while x == 1:

    if time1 == 10:
        time1 = time1 - 1
    elif time1 == 0:
        time1 = time1 + 1
    else :
        time1 = time1 + 1
    print time1
    time.sleep(time1)
```

So I changed the program around abit, so I almost works correctly. What it does is count to 10, then 9 then back to 10.
ex. 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,9,10,9,10
how can I set it so that the program increases time to ten then decreases to zero then increases again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're overriding the imported `time` module (line 1) by your own `time` variable (line 4). You can:

- rename your `time` variable to something else

  ```
  import time
  x = 1
  t = 1
  time_passed = t + 1 # use "time_passed" instead of "time" for example
  while x == 1:
      print time_passed
      if time_passed >= 10:
          time_passed = t - 1
      elif time_passed <= 0:
          time_passed = t + 1
      time.sleep(time_passed)
  ```
- alias the imported `time` module with `import time as tm` the use `tm.sleep(time)`

  ```
  import time as tm # alias the time module as "tm" for example
  x = 1
  t = 1
  time  = t + 1
  while x == 1:
      print time
      if time >= 10:
          time = t - 1
      elif time <= 0:
          time = t + 1
      tm.sleep(time) # use "tm" to refer to the module
  ```
- only import `sleep` from `time` with `from time import sleep` and use `sleep(time)` instead

  ```
  from time import sleep # only import "sleep" from time, not the whole module
  x = 1
  t = 1
  time  = t + 1
  while x == 1:
      print time
      if time >= 10:
          time = t - 1
      elif time <= 0:
          time = t + 1
      sleep(time) # use "sleep" directly
  ```

---

After fixing this, you also need to somehow remember that you need to either increase or decrease the time at the next iteration. For example:

```
from time import sleep
x = 1
t = 1
time  = t + 1
incr = True
while x == 1:
    print time
    if time >= 10:
        time = 9
        incr = False
    elif time <= 0:
        time = t + 1
        incr = True
    else:
        if incr:
            time = time + 1
        else:
            time = time - 1
    sleep(time)
```

Comment: The third solution is probably the best

Answer (score 4):

You're redefining 'time' after you import it...

Try using a different variable name.

Answer (score 3):

Your `time` variable is conflicting with the module (`time`) that you imported. You could use `curTime` or `myTime` instead as your variable name.